# QWidget shown problems after QStackedLayout setCurrentIndex

Tags: c++, qt

I have a task which was to show a dialog beside the windows desk's edge. When the mouse move to the specific regions(some where in the windows desk), the dialog shows, while out it'll be hide.

I put some QWidget in the dialog with QStackedLayout used as layout,
and use QStackedLayout::setCurrentIndex to change the current widget before the dialog shown.

The problem is that the previous widget will stay a littel while when the dialog is shown, and then the new widget is shown. And what i want is to show the new widget immediately.

So why is that happen, and how can i fix it?

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(int role, QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::ConfigDialog)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::SubWindow | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
// here is the code i commented out and the problem seems to be gone
//  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  buttonArea = new QRect();
  canReShow = true;
  init(role);
}

ConfigDialog::~ConfigDialog()
{
  delete ui;
}

void ConfigDialog::setModel(int model)
{
  int tmp = model;
  QStackedLayout* lay = qobject_cast<QStackedLayout*>(layout());
  if (lay->count() < tmp || tmp < 0)
  {
    tmp = 0;
  }
  lay->setCurrentIndex(tmp);
}

void ConfigDialog::init(int role)
{
  QStackedLayout* stackLayout = new QStackedLayout(this);
  stackLayout->setMargin(0);
  stackLayout->setSpacing(0);

  // 根据系统缩放比例，缩放窗口
  qreal scale = ::GetDpiForSystem() / 96;
  int iconWidth = 64 * scale;
  int iconHeight = 64 * scale;

  // system menu
  QWidget* syscfg = new QWidget(this);

  QHBoxLayout* lay = new QHBoxLayout(syscfg);
  lay->setSpacing(0);
  lay->setMargin(0);
  lay->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

  lay->addStretch();

  QPushButton* btnSysConfig = new QPushButton(syscfg);
  QIcon syscfgIcon;
  syscfgIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/console.png");
  btnSysConfig->setIcon(syscfgIcon);
  btnSysConfig->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnSysConfig->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnSysConfig, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit sysConfig();
    accept();
  });
  lay->addWidget(btnSysConfig);

  if (2 != role)
  {
    QPushButton* btnUserConfig = new QPushButton(syscfg);
    QIcon usrcfgIcon;
    usrcfgIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/setting.png");
    btnUserConfig->setIcon(usrcfgIcon);
    btnUserConfig->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
    btnUserConfig->setFlat(true);
    connect(btnUserConfig, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
    {
      emit userConfig();
      accept();
    });
    lay->addWidget(btnUserConfig);
  }

  QPushButton* btnExitApp = new QPushButton(syscfg);
  QIcon exitIcon;
  exitIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/exit.png");
  btnExitApp->setIcon(exitIcon);
  btnExitApp->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnExitApp->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnExitApp, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit exitSys();
    //    accept();
  });

  lay->addWidget(btnExitApp);
  lay->addStretch();

  stackLayout->addWidget(syscfg);
  // end system menu

  // app menu
  QWidget* appcfg = new QWidget(this);
  lay = new QHBoxLayout(appcfg);
  lay->setSpacing(0);
  lay->setMargin(0);

  lay->addStretch();

  QPushButton* btnResetWindow = new QPushButton(appcfg);
  QIcon resetIcon;
  resetIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/reset.png");
  btnResetWindow->setIcon(resetIcon);
  btnResetWindow->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnResetWindow->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnResetWindow, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit resetWindow();
    accept();
    setModel();
  });
  lay->addWidget(btnResetWindow);

  lay->addStretch();

  stackLayout->addWidget(appcfg);
  // end app menu

  // web menu
  QWidget* webcfg = new QWidget(this);
  lay = new QHBoxLayout(webcfg);
  lay->setSpacing(0);
  lay->setMargin(0);

  lay->addStretch();

  // reset
  btnResetWindow = new QPushButton(webcfg);
  btnResetWindow->setIcon(resetIcon);
  btnResetWindow->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnResetWindow->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnResetWindow, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit resetWindow();
    accept();
    setModel();
  });
  lay->addWidget(btnResetWindow);

  // back
  QPushButton* btnBackward = new QPushButton(webcfg);
  QIcon backIcon;
  backIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/back.png");
  btnBackward->setIcon(backIcon);
  btnBackward->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnBackward->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnBackward, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit backWard();
    accept();
  });
  lay->addWidget(btnBackward);

  // forward
  QPushButton* btnForward = new QPushButton(webcfg);
  QIcon forwardIcon;
  forwardIcon.addFile(":/icon/icon/front.png");
  btnForward->setIcon(forwardIcon);
  btnForward->setIconSize(QSize(iconWidth, iconHeight));
  btnForward->setFlat(true);
  connect(btnForward, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
  {
    emit forWard();
    accept();
  });
  lay->addWidget(btnForward);

  lay->addStretch();

  stackLayout->addWidget(webcfg);
  // end web menu

  // show & hide test
  showHideTest = new QTimer(this);
  connect(showHideTest, &QTimer::timeout, [this]()
  {
    QScreen* screen = qApp->primaryScreen();
    auto testArea = new QRect(0, 0, screen->size().width(), rect().height());
    if (testArea->contains(cursor().pos()))
    {
      if (canReShow)
      {
        show();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      canReShow = true;
      hideTest->stop();
      hoverTest->stop();
      accept();
    }
  });
  showHideTest->start(30);

  // hover test
  // 当处于非有效区域（对话框之外）5秒后，对话框隐藏
  hoverTest = new QTimer(this);
  connect(hoverTest, &QTimer::timeout, [this]()
  {
    qDebug() << buttonArea->left() << buttonArea->right() << cursor().pos();
    if (buttonArea->contains(cursor().pos()))
    {
      canReShow = true;
      hideTest->stop();
    }
    else
    {
      canReShow = false;
      if (!hideTest->isActive())
      {
        hideTest->start(5000);
      }
    }
  });

  // hide when hover time out
  hideTest = new QTimer(this);
  connect(hideTest, &QTimer::timeout, [this]()
  {
    hideTest->stop();
    hoverTest->stop();
    accept();
  });
}

bool ConfigDialog::event(QEvent *e)
{
  if (e->type() == QEvent::Show)
  {
    QScreen* screen = qApp->primaryScreen();
    QSize curSize = size();
    QPoint point(screen->size().width() / 2 - curSize.width() / 2, 0);
    move(point);

    buttonArea->setTopLeft(point);
    buttonArea->setSize(size());

    // 启动悬停检测
    hoverTest->start(30);
  }

  //  if (e->type() == QEvent::Leave)
  //  {
  //    QScreen* screen = qApp->primaryScreen();
  //    auto testArea = new QRect(0, 0, screen->size().width(), rect().height());
  //    if (!testArea->contains(cursor().pos()))
  //    {
  //      hideTest->stop();
  //      hoverTest->stop();
  //      accept();
  //    }
  //  }
  //  qDebug() << "----------------------- config dialog event: " << e->type();
  return QWidget::event(e);
}

void ConfigDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.fillRect(rect(), QColor(49, 52, 58, 255));
}
```

Comment: After some trying, I may have figure out the cause of the problem: i commented out the code "setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground)" wrote in the dialog's init function, it looks that the problem is gone.But i still don't understand why?

Comment: It's very unlikely that anyone will be able to help you without seeing your code -- a [mcve] if possible.  You might also want to add a language tag -- `C++`?